# Dask aws cluster error when initializing: User data is limited to 16384 bytes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, conda, dask, dask-distributed

I'm following the guide here: https://cloudprovider.dask.org/en/latest/packer.html#ec2cluster-with-rapids

In particular I set up my instance with packer, and am now trying to run the final piece of code:

```
cluster = EC2Cluster(
            ami=pack_ami,  # AMI ID provided by Packer
            region="eu-west-2",
            docker_image="rapidsai/rapidsai:cuda10.1-runtime-ubuntu18.04-py3.8",
            instance_type="p3.2xlarge",
            bootstrap=False,
            filesystem_size=120,
        )
cluster.scale(1)
client = Client(cluster)
```

Note that I had to add the region to avoid complaining. Unfortunately now I get this error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the RunInstances operation: User data is limited to 16384 bytes
```

when `Creating scheduler instance`.

Full trace here:

```
Creating scheduler instance
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tpotmodel.py", line 124, in <module>
    main()
  File "tpotmodel.py", line 83, in main
    bootstrap=False,
  File "/home/simon/.conda/envs/tpot-cuml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask_cloudprovider/aws/ec2.py", line 474, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/home/simon/.conda/envs/tpot-cuml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask_cloudprovider/generic/vmcluster.py", line 284, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs, security=self.security)
  File "/home/simon/.conda/envs/tpot-cuml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/spec.py", line 281, in __init__
    self.sync(self._start)
  File "/home/simon/.conda/envs/tpot-cuml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/cluster.py", line 189, in sync
    return sync(self.loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/simon/.conda/envs/tpot-cuml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 340, in sync
    raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/simon/.conda/envs/tpot-cuml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 324, in f
    result[0] = yield future
  File "/home/simon/.conda/envs/tpot-cuml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home/simon/.conda/envs/tpot-cuml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask_cloudprovider/generic/vmcluster.py", line 324, in _start
    await super()._start()
  File "/home/simon/.conda/envs/tpot-cuml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/spec.py", line 309, in _start
    self.scheduler = await self.scheduler
  File "/home/simon/.conda/envs/tpot-cuml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/spec.py", line 71, in _
    await self.start()
  File "/home/simon/.conda/envs/tpot-cuml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask_cloudprovider/generic/vmcluster.py", line 86, in start
    ip = await self.create_vm()
  File "/home/simon/.conda/envs/tpot-cuml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask_cloudprovider/aws/ec2.py", line 139, in create_vm
    response = await client.run_instances(**vm_kwargs)
  File "/home/simon/.conda/envs/tpot-cuml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiobotocore/client.py", line 154, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the RunInstances operation: User data is limited to 16384 bytes
```

I'm on arch with conda if that changes anything.

Comment: Dask Community is tracking this problem here: https://github.com/dask/dask-cloudprovider/issues/249 and a potential solution https://github.com/dask/distributed/pull/4465.  if you are willing/able can you test out PR 4465 ?

Comment: Thank you! This worked, it's not a final solution but I consider those links a solution, if you post it as an answer I will accept.

Comment: addendum: worked partially, see the PR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dask Community is tracking this problem here: [github.com/dask/dask-cloudprovider/issues/249](http://github.com/dask/dask-cloudprovider/issues/249) and a potential solution [github.com/dask/distributed/pull/4465](http://github.com/dask/distributed/pull/4465). 4465 should resolve the issues.